# Excel doesn't prompt for 'Enable Content' on downloaded files

Tags: excel, vba, security

This is a very strange problem so if you think I didn't ask it right, please let me know so I may revise my question.

Case is that I send a macro enabled file to a friend who opens it, clicks on enable editing button and then clicks on enable content button. Then he clicks on button and the macro runs fine. Up to here it is fine but...

Next time when he closes the file and opens the file again, he clicks on macro button, its says, "Cannot run the macro ... This macro may not be available in this workbook or all the macros may be disabled".

Then he tries to download this file again but this time the file gives option to 'Enable editing' but DOES NOT give option button for 'Enable content'. And again pressing the macro button gives above error.

Strangely this same macro file has worked fine on few other computers I have tried.

OTHER INFO ABOUT FRIENDS' COMPUTER
WINDOWS 10, NORTON ANTIVIRUS

WHAT HAVE WE ALREADY TRIED is as follows;

> Disabling Norton Antivirus

> Sending other macro enabled files from my computer to friend's computer. Those also work same, work on first time download and then stop working same way.

> Checked 'Enable All Macros' setting in Excel Trust Center Macro Settings.

> Tried in Excel 2010 and Excel 2016.

> Created new macro enabled file on Friend's computer in which created macros work fine.

> Enabled "Trust access to the VBA project object model" in Macro settings.

Please suggest the right solution. Why is the macro disabled in downloaded file and not working with any effort. Thanks

Comment: Please do not include external links to macro enabled files in your question.

Comment: How can I attach a macro enabled file? Because here the question is not about macro, it is about whole file security setting.

Comment: Your question does not require you to attach a file. The user's security settings have nothing to do with the file itself, and you do not have control over them. The user does.

Comment: Why not believe the message? If the user opens the file, runs the macro and then saves it in XLSX format the macro wouldn't be available on next try.

Comment: User does not save it to xlsx. The macro in downloaded file just does not work.